# Assembling meta-analysis data with paired data for metafor

Tags: meta-analysis

I am trying to assemble a meta-analytic dataset for computing **yi** and **vi** for metafor. For this dataset, I am including paired data (i.e., one sample of participants that completed upright and inverted face recognition task (% correct)). The problem is that half of the studies include the *M*, *SD*, and *N*, which can be used to compute the "standardized mean change" score in escalc() as shown below.

```
escalc(measure = "SMCR", m1i = upright_mean, sd1i = upright_sd,
                 m2i= inverted_mean, sd2i = inverted_sd, ri = ri, ni= N, data = rawData)
```

The other half of the studies only include the paired t-statistic and/or p-value. I would like to know if it is possible to assemble all of these studies into the same measure of Cohen's *d*, *yi*, and sampling variance, *vi*. and if so, how to accomplish that? I have not been able to figure out how to compute both yi and vi when only the paired t-statistic is available.

Comment: If a reasonable number of studies have both raw and derived estimates of effect you could try multivariate meta-analysis (or as a last resort missing data imputation).